# Do we need both A and MX record for a stmp server in DNS

Tags: dns

Recently, i delete a DNS A record corresponding to a smtp server. The original DNS conf is like below:

```
mail.demo.com    MX    192.168.3.3
mail.demo.com    A     192.168.3.3
```

After delete the MX record, i try a Python script try to connect to my mail.demo.com. The script is like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


def send_mail(to_list,sub):
    me = "demo<demo@localhost>"

    msg = MIMEText("")
    msg['Subject'] = sub
    msg['From'] = me
    msg['To'] = ";".join(to_list)

    try:
        s = smtplib.SMTP()
        s.connect("mail.demo.com")
        s.sendmail(me, to_list, msg.as_string())
        s.close()
        return True
    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if send_mail(["jack@mail.demo.com"], "hello"):
        print "success"
    else:
        print "fail"
```

Something is wrong, the with "no address with associated hosts". 
So, i am curous about:

- why we need the A record to exist to connect to mail.demo.com
- when we actually use the MX record.

Answer (score 1):

An MX record contains two pieces of data: a priority number, and a domain name of a mail server. Someone trying to deliver mail will take the domain name of the mail server, use it to look up an IP address and then try to connect to that IP address.

`192.168.3.3` is not a valid domain name. Using it to try to look up an IP address fails, so the attempt to deliver mail fails for lack of anything to connect to (some delivery programs may go "Hey, that name looks an awful lot like an IP address, let's give that a go!", but that is not something you can rely on).

What you should have is an MX record with a *name* in it, and then an A record *for that name* with an IP address in it.